# Relative an element to its next element which has absolute position

Tags: css

I need to be move an element using position absolute and i want to make it relative with its previous element..

my code format:

```
<div>
    <div class="one" style="position:relative"></div>
    <span class="two" style="position:absolute"></span>
</div>
```

the span need to move which relative with the div which has class one.

Comment: to do this, the span will be inside div class one

Answer (score -1):

The absolute is always relative to the first parent witg positioning. So you can only do what you are requesting with js and not using only CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Put `.two` inside `.one` and adjust it's position. Than moving `.one` will also move `.two`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.one').animate({
      left: '100px'
    }, 500);
  }, 1000);
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.one').animate({
      left: '300px'
    }, 500);
  }, 1600);
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.one').animate({
      left: '200px'
    }, 500);
  }, 2200);
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.one').animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 500);
  }, 2800);
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="one" style="position:relative">
    <span class="two" style="position:absolute"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
    <div class="one" style="position:relative">
        <span class="two" style="position:absolute"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```